# How to doing cashing with list In Moss 2007?

Tags: 2007, 2010, caching, wss

i have no idea that hows to doing cashing in Moss? In my application during page load taking so much time around 20sec. so i want to reduce this time period.

Problem is that i have retrieved data from 3 lists and so much condition in my code. can i doing caching with lists? Is this providing in SharePoint?
if i m going wrong related this topics. pl guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PortalSiteMapProvider which is leverage object cache in MOSS. CQWP is also uses it

Comment: i had follow ur guide and searching on net to found some helpful link.                                    http://www.zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-developing-for-performance-part-3-caching-in-sharepoint-2010
                                   http://www.theblackknightsings.com/CachingASharePointListAsADatatable.aspx

http://blogs.mosshosting.com/archive/2009/01/09/considerations-for-working-with-sharepoint-lists-programmatically.aspx                                        Hops someone helpful this link.Thnks